# Can AMOS be used to perform logistic regressions?

Tags: spss, modeling, amos

I need to compare 11 groups of data, for the same relationship.

My first thoughts were to create 11 regression equations (one for each), and to compare parameters between groups.

Problem is that depended variable is a dummy variable and I need to compute a logistic or probit model. In SPSS everything is okay.

But AMOS give such a nice visualization of the model (s) (relatively complicated), and I want to compute each of logistic (or probit) regression equation in AMOS. Is this possible? If yes, please give me some places where to  look for the commands and steps for this kind of analyses

Comment: It would help your audience, if you explained what AMOS was. Consider editing your question (the "edit" link in the lower left) to improve.

Comment: [Amos](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/spss-amos) is SPSS' SEM software.

Comment: Why not add an interaction term and run a multiple logistic regression?

Comment: Could you explain further your suggestion please? I'm not familiar with " interaction term" and have such a brief time to analyse my data. What is missing in my statistical model? I can feel something isn't accurate.

Comment: Can you upload an example of AMOS' visualization tools of which you're so fond?

Comment: The big issue is if AMOS can handle categorical dependent variables.  Some SEM software can, some can't.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, sort of, but only using the Bayesian approach.

Use lavaan, an R package, and you can do this.

You can also do this using an interaction term (or set of interaction terms) using the logistic regression function in SPSS.

Comment: Yes Sir, I understand this. But my concern was in regard of statistical Package AMOS. In on-line materials (tutorials etc.) there is no explanation if AMOS contains  logistic regression analysis... Many thanks for your reply

Answer (score 1):

AMOS can run logistic regressions but I obtained different results for a logistic regression conducted in SPSS AMOS or conducted in SPSS. This might be according to your AMOS version and license.

To be sure, I focus on SPSS.

For more information - [Intro to AMOS Bayesian SEM and MCMC](http://www.structuralequations.com/AmosTutorials.html)